# Looking for a story about a paleontologist uncovering fossilised dinosaur tracks who finds that it is chasing a jeep

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel, dinosaurs

Looking for a short story from probably 70s or 80s.

I can't remember most details but I think it involves a paleontologist and another scientist chatting. The paleontologist is in a desert and uncovering a series of fossilised footprints of a dinosaur that appears to be chasing something.

The other scientist is deliberately vague about what is going on at a hush-hush establishment nearby and the whole establishment eventually disappears. The paleontologist continues to uncover the footprints and is unsurprised when he finds that the dinosaur is chasing a jeep.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

[Time's Arrow](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time%27s_Arrow_(short_story)) by Arthur C. Clarke

> Fowler is invited to visit Henderson's lab, during which time the two
> geologists come to believe that the physicist is trying to effectively
> build a way to view the past firsthand. Henderson confirms their
> conclusion and asks Fowler to join him during the machine's first test
> run. The dig continues and the team discovers that the footprints give
> off the impression that the dinosaur was chasing something. Fowler
> sets off for the lab via Jeep, shortly after which Davis sees the lab
> explode and the surrounding area ripple. He returns to alert Barton,
> who has discovered that the dinosaur tracks are accompanied by Jeep
> tyre prints, implying that the dinosaur had chased after and
> subsequently trampled Fowler.

Comment: Thank you, that was impressive. Did you do it from memory or superior search-skills?

Comment: I remembered reading it in The Best Time Travel Stories of the 20th Century so I checked the table of contents for that book and found it.  Give me a checkmark if you're satisfied with the answer

Answer (score 11):

This triggered something *deep* in my subconscious. I think Time's Arrow is probably the correct answer, but the same scene was (shamelessly copied?) in a Tom Swift & Hardy Boys crossover called [Time Bomb](http://www.hardyboysonline.net/content.php?page=book&id=ut-001) I read when I was very young. I can't find much of a plot summary anywhere, but as it appears there were only two such crossover novels, this has to be it.